# image now showing when called from database

Tags: php, mysql, image, directory

SOLVED!

so ive created an image upload page which saves the image to a folder and sends the file name to the DB, ive checked to see if they are actually being added to the DB and folder which they are, but when i call the data to another page to display the images i get broken images.

below is my code to call the images, its some code ive scraped together from various tutorials as they gave me the same problem as im having now.

UPDATE:
ive managed to get the images showing but now im faced with being shown the same image for each row of data called, the id and img_name and right for each row but the image is always the same as the first listed.

UPDATED CODE:

```
<?php
//connect to database
include ('connect.php');

//save the name of image in table
$query = mysql_query("select * from tbl_img") or die(mysql_error());

//retrieve all image from database and store them in a variable
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $img_name = $row['img'];
}
?>



<?php

include ('connect.php');

$img_id = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_img");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($img_id))
{

$id = $row['img_id'];

echo "
$id<br>
$img_name<br>
<img src='http://localhost/testarea/include/site_images/$img_name' />
";

echo "<br><br><br></p>
";

}

?>
```

Comment: When you `echo` the `$img_name` variable, what does it return ?

Comment: test_image1.gif and all the subsequent file names i have in tbl_img

Comment: Ok. And what if you put your absolute path in the image src. Ex: `<img src='http://localhost:8080/include/site_images/$img_name' />`

Comment: returns the same broken image

Comment: Is the folder includes contained in your DocumentRoot? If it is not, and it is in the same folder as the script, remove / before includes

Comment: checking the image element in google chrome shows the image is pointing to the correct file

Comment: or use firebug to check if the image is retrieving from the correct place. If not you will see a 404 error on that petition.

Comment: everything i check says its pointing to the correct place/file

Comment: ive managed a work around but now ran into a different problem

Answer (score 0):

If you start the path  of image with / you mean an absolute path where / is the DocumentRoot folder  (or the directory of virtualhost)

With src ="includes/xxx/image.png" you mean that includes is in the same folder with the php script. If it is not you can use relative path like

src="../includes/xxx/image.png"  for example

Comment: ive managed a work around but now ran into a different problem, ive updated the main question with new code and the new problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

include ('connect.php');

$img_id = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_img");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($img_id))
{
$img_name = $row['img'];
$id = $row['img_id'];

echo "
$id<br>
$img_name<br>
<img src='http://localhost/testarea/include/site_images/$img_name' />
";

echo "<br><br><br></p>
";

}
```

Comment: with your code $img_name is altered in each iteration in the first while but it is not altered in the second while loop